# Get parent key in UITableview with firebase

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have my firebase database structured like this:

```
Snap (-KWLSAIh5WJvNJOkxBEr) {
  beschrijving = "description";
  image = "link to image";
  title = "title";
}
Snap (-KWLSTak0H20X_2Qnanv) {
  beschrijving = "description";
  image = "link to image";
  title = "title";
}
```

This is the code I am using to display this in a TableView:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class NieuwsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var users = [UsersII]()
let cellId = "IdCell"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    fetchUser()
}
func fetchUser() {
    Database.database().reference().child("Blog").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            let user = UsersII(dictionary: dictionary)
            self.users.append(user)

            print(snapshot)


            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })

        }


    }, withCancel: nil)
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return users.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> lllTableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)

    let user = users.reversed()[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = user.name

    return cell as! lllTableViewCell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let message = users.reversed()[indexPath.row]

    guard let beschrijving = message.beschrijving else {
        return
    }
    guard let image = message.plaatje else {
        return
    }
    guard let titel = message.name else {
        return
    }


    UserDefaults.standard.set(beschrijving, forKey: "nieuwsBeschrijving")
    UserDefaults.standard.set(image,forKey: "nieuwsPlaatje")
    UserDefaults.standard.set(titel, forKey: "nieuwsTitel")


    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotonews", sender: nil)
}

}
```

And I don't know if you will need this to answer this question but I'll also post the "UsersII" (defined as users just above the viewDidLoad method) in case this is needed to answer the question.

```
 import UIKit

class UsersII: NSObject {
 var name: String?
 var beschrijving: String?
 var plaatje: String?
 init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
    self.name = dictionary["title"] as? String ?? ""
    self.beschrijving = dictionary["beschrijving"] as? String ?? ""
    self.plaatje = dictionary["image"] as? String ?? ""
 }
}
```

so what I want to achieve is that if you click on one of the cells, you get the parent id of the article, so in this case that would be the "-KWLSAIh5WJvNJOkxBEr or -KWLSTak0H20X_2Qnanv" I mentioned above in my firebase database structure.

Comment: You can get the parent id of the article by calling snapshot.key inside firebse child added observer and then add it in you model class.

Comment: Also, you should change `AnyObject` to `Any`, as that is the Swift way.  And why does `UsersII` need to be a subclass of `NSObject`?

Comment: @Y_Y what's my model class? I'm sorry if it's a stupid question I'm kinda new to all this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i was saying you to do:
**Your model class:**

```
class UsersII: NSObject {
var parentId: String?
var name: String?
var beschrijving: String?
var plaatje: String?
init(dictionary: [String: Any],parentId:String) {
 self.name = dictionary["title"] as? String ?? ""
 self.beschrijving = dictionary["beschrijving"] as? String ?? ""
 self.plaatje = dictionary["image"] as? String ?? ""
 self.parentId = parentId
 }
}
```

**Fetch user method:**

```
  func fetchUser() {
   Database.database().reference().child("Blog").observe(.childAdded,        with: { (snapshot) in

    if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
        let user = UsersII(dictionary: dictionary,parentId:snapshot.key)
        self.users.append(user)

        print(snapshot)


        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        })

    }


 }, withCancel: nil)
}
```

**And finaly you didSelect:**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
let message = users.reversed()[indexPath.row]

guard let beschrijving = message.beschrijving else {
    return
}
guard let image = message.plaatje else {
    return
}
guard let titel = message.name else {
    return
}

guard let parentId = message.name else
{
   return
 }

UserDefaults.standard.set(beschrijving, forKey: "nieuwsBeschrijving")
UserDefaults.standard.set(image,forKey: "nieuwsPlaatje")
UserDefaults.standard.set(titel, forKey: "nieuwsTitel")
UserDefaults.standard.set(parentId,forKey: "nieuwsParentId")

self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotonews", sender: nil)
 }

}
```